# How can I initialize this character array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, char, initialization

```
        final int SIZE= 10;
        char[][] board= new char[SIZE][SIZE];
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {for(int j=0;j<10;j++) {board[i][j]=' ';}}
        
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            String K=Integer.toString(i);
            board[0][i]=K.charAt(0); board[i][0]=board[0][i];   }
        
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++) {
                System.out.print(board[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
```

And I got this;

```
0123456789   
1         
2         
3         
4         
5         
6         
7         
8         
9
```

`char[0][0]` is not ' '. I want to initialize `char[0][0]`.

Comment: Start your second loop at `i=1` to skip filling the [0][0] index.

Comment: Your error description is btw really not great. `board[0][0]` is initialized. You just override its value later on. So constantly saying you want to initialize that value really doesn't tell people here what you actualy want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct what you want. You want that board[0][0] = ' '.
That it should be like that:

```
    final int SIZE = 10; // You wrote in for loop 10 instead SIZE but it would be better
                         // to write the size variable in loop if it declared.
    char[][] board = new char[SIZE][SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            board[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }

    /*
      1) i should start with 1 because you want that board[0][0] = ' '
      2) When you write a variable that is not final, it should be start
         with lower case and end with lower case
    */


    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++) {
        board[0][i] = String.valueOf(i).charAt(0);
        board[i][0] = board[0][i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            System.out.print(board[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

The output:

' '123456789

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9